# Exporting current color setting to a custom theme

Tags: visual-studio

I have my own custom VS color set that I made by editing the colors in the setting and I have been using it for more than an year now. I wanted to make it into an extension and tried with "Visual Studio Color Theme Designer" but there is no option for importing current colors into the theme. Is there any way I can achieve what I want? I am on VS 2022.